# Copy ehcache from one server to another

Tags: java, ehcache

I have a tomcat server with ehcache. And I have a second tomcat with servlet. When second servlet is inited it should take ehcache from #1 and put all data to its cache.

Is there built-in mechanism such "on start replication" in ehcache? Or how can I get serialized ehcache data and then de-serialize them to ehcache. I understand that I can read all keys one by one and then all their values then serialize but maybe there's a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/replication/rmi-replicated-caching.html ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box support for what you are asking.

Alternatives are:

- Ehcache clustering with [Terracotta](http://terracotta.org/downloads/open-source/catalog)
- Ehcache [replication](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/replication/rmi-replicated-caching.html)

Note that a major difference between the two is that the second option offers NO guarantees with regards to data consistency between the two Ehcache instances.

Disclaimer: I work for Terracotta on Ehcache

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using built-in rmi replication solution:

Master config:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
     updateCheck="true"
     monitoring="autodetect"
     dynamicConfig="true">

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
        properties="hostName=localhost, port=40001,
socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>

<cache name="masterCache"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="300"
       timeToLiveSeconds="600"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       transactionalMode="off">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
            properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=false, replicateUpdates=false,
    replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=false "/>
    <persistence strategy="none"/>
</cache>
```

Here I turn on RMI listener for slaves and enable RMI for cache but without any replication because I just need data on slave when it starts and that's all

Slave config:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
     updateCheck="true"
     monitoring="autodetect"
     dynamicConfig="true">

<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
rmiUrls=//localhost:40001/masterCache"/>


<cache name="masterCache"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="300"
       timeToLiveSeconds="600"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       transactionalMode="off">
    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
                                 properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=false"/>
    <persistence strategy="none"/>
</cache>
```

I made RMI connection to master node and turn on cache's bootstrap.